# data is showing undefine how would it could correct

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

This is **error**:

> D:\LCO bootcamp\Project_Backend\controllers\product.js:50
> product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(file.photo.path);
> ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'data')

Code:

```
if (file.photo) {
      if (file.photo.size > 3000000) {
        return res.status(400).json({
          error: "File size too big!"
        });
    }

      
      product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(file.photo.filepath);
      product.photo.contentType = file.photo.mimetype;
}
```

'

Comment: please help me to remove this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(file.photo.filepath)` and `product.photo.contentType = file.photo.mimetype` to inside `if(product.photo){...}` :

```
if (file.photo) {
          if (file.photo.size > 3000000) {
            return res.status(400).json({
              error: "File size too big!"
            });
        }
    
          if(product.photo){
            product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(file.photo.filepath);
            product.photo.contentType = file.photo.mimetype;
          }
          
    }
```